# Gear setup for 12 V motor

Tags: gears

I'm looking for a ring gear 8 - 10 inches in diameter and the small gear to turn it that will fit on a 12 V motor with a 6 mm - 8 mm in diameter spindle for this [motor here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GBVDRG1). I've been searching for days and don't seem to be coming up with the right search terms. Something similar to how a starter turns a flywheel but a starter motor is overkill and won't work. A chain and sprocket would even work but I can't find a sprocket small enough to fit on the motor.

Comment: You need to ask an actual question ending with a '?'. Note that you need to avoid direct shopping questions which are off-topic but asking for correct terminology or search terms is fine. There's an [Edit] link below your question ...

Comment: Finding gears is just difficult in general, let alone something like a ring gear, let alone a massive ring gear. You're into specialty suppliers and "whoever needs this type of part probably just has it made" territory. If you're using a motor off Amazon and trying to search for other parts off Amazon, I'm going to take a guess and say this project is beyond your budget. See the price in this one example: https://www.mcmaster.com/2696N33/

Comment: Good to know. I decided just to try and cut them out of plexiglass. Hopefully that'll work.